# How do I make a POST call from C# that accepts a CSV file as a response?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am making a POST method call to a Web API from C# and trying to accept a CSV file as a response. But, my code is throwing this error:

> The remote server returned an error: (415) Unsupported Media Type.

My function to make the call is as follows:

```cs
    public void dataPost()
    {           
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://example.com");
        var postData = "filename=filename";            
        var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;

        using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }

        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse(); //fails on this line

        var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());           
    }
```

Any kind of help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try adding:

```
request.Accept = "text/csv";
```

Comment: I tried to do that but now it's throwing another error: **The remote server returned an error: (406) Not Acceptable.** Any ideas about what to do?